# I cannot build my web application unless I end-task w3wp.exe

Tags: .net, iis

I have a web application (.NET 5.0). The moment I add it to IIS (10) as an application, `w3wp.exe` locks the `.dll` files and I cannot build my code unless I end-task `w3wp.exe`. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What are you referring to when saying "I cannot build my code"? Are you building your code in Visual Studio or not?

Comment: @LexLi yes, I cannot build it in Visual Studio.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio 2019 are you using? This issue has been reported and resolved in 16.4, https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/bin-files-locked-by-iis-worker-process-1/546858 If your VS version is higher than that, you have to report it to Microsoft once again.